# python pandas -use WECO rule to score groupby and output groupby score

Tags: python, pandas, scoring

So I have all th WECO rules I wrote and it works--on a column of data.
But now I want to group by 'name' and then score the 'score' column.
and my problem is using groupby and trying to output to new df2
-This will be for a many datasets with 5 - 40+ names
-This is one of the rules:

```
WECO_A = ["N"]
UCL = .2

lastPoint=df.groupby('name').iloc[0]['score']

if lastPoint > UCL:
    WECO_A = "Y"

if WECO_A == "Y":
    df2['weco'] = df.groupby('name') + 'RULE_A'

else:
    df2['weco'] = df.groupby('name') + 'OK'
```

df:
name    score
bob     0.2849
sue     0.1960
ken     0.8427
bob     0.2844
sue     0.2507
ken     0.9904
...etc

and I am looking for this

df2:
name    weco
bob     RULE_A
sue     OK
ken     RULE_A

OR even a single column,

df2:
weco
bob RULE_A
sue OK
ken RULE_A

-just an example not sure what real scores would be??
AND, thanks in advance as always..

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  You'll get better answers, faster, that way, and it will be more useful for others trying to learn from your post.

Comment: Yeah sorry about that - I am not sure If I am asking for the groupby data/scoring wrong, or just the output - so I put the whole thing in. I will try again maybe with just one Rule example??

Comment: Make sure you provide an example representation of `df`.

Comment: sure thing - I edited this question, to make it shorter and more to the point.

Comment: where is `df2` defined?  also, please provide the exact expected output based on the `df` you've provided. Otherwise it makes it hard to verify you're getting the answer you're looking for.

Comment: your updated post is so truncated that the `OK` and `RULE_B` branches aren't there anymore.  so it's not clear how to generate the expected output you've provided.

Comment: thanks again for helping me refine this - only my 4th question

Comment: have you tried running your code on the example `df` you provided?  For one thing, `try` will fail without an `except`.  But even when I remove `try`, I get an error with `iloc` after `groupby`: `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'iloc' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`